# How can I insert a new line into a text file into every other 2 lines?

Tags: shell, unix-text-processing

Starting with this,

example.txt

```
1.qwer
2.asdf
3.xzcv
4.cbvn
5.erty
```

Going to this,

apendedtext.txt

```
1.append
2.qwer
3.asdf
4.append
5.xzcv
6.cbvn
7.append
```

Comment: Your file has line numbers in it that you want updated too?

Comment: yes 
lucaslugao answered my question perfectly

Comment: @an0nhi11 can you accept the answer then?

Comment: @lucaslugao done thanks. I didnt know about that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you added the line numbers for simplicity and that the output is missing the 8th line "erty" you can get around with a simple awk one-liner:

```sh
#                                     ┌─ input      ┌─ output
awk 'NR % 2 {print "append"} {print}' < example.txt > apendedtext.txt
#     │                      └─ Print the original line
#     └─ Append if line has even index
```

If you want to manipulate the line numbers too you could remove and add them back:

```sh
( sed -E 's/[0-9]*\.//g'| awk 'NR % 2 {print (++i) "." "append"} {print (++i) "." $0}' ) < example.txt > apendedtext.txt
#           └─ Remove line number               └─   Prepend a counter  ─┘
```

Comment: I love your commenting style. I may have to steal it!

Answer (score 0):

awk ' {print;} NR % 2 == 0 { print "append"; }' example.txt > appended.txt

Comment: The order is reversed, you want to print the original line after printing "append".

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.